# best way to recognize this pattern?

Tags: python, transform

i want to recognize a pattern, just a list of four double numbers. say List (L)
e.g. 0,3,1,2

the criteria is ,

```
L[1] > L[0]
L[2] < L[1] and L[2] > L[0]
L[3] < L[1]
```

it's like a sin wave, i want to know if there's a simple way to do above iterative check, something like a FFT ? but just for a series of 4 numbers, it's not so beneficial to use transforms.

thanks

Comment: You can wrap your logic into a function?

Comment: Just write the compound `if` statement.  What does that not accomplish for you?

Comment: If you want this for the specific case of 4 numbers with the criteria you described, you just have to `and` those comparisons into an `if` statement...

Comment: right. simplest way is to put in a function, what if there's more complicated shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to just iterate over that you can simply put it into a function i suppose as James said. Maybe something like the following is what you are looking for.

```
L = [0,3,1,2]
def check(L):
    return L[1] > L[0] and L[2] < L[1] and L[2] > L[0] and L[3] < L[1]

print(check(L))
```

Comment: Just `return L[1] > L[0] and L[2] < L[1] and L[2] > L[0] and L[3] < L[1]` would do. No need to use an `if ` statement to make a Boolean expression out of a Boolean expression.